# Gcloud ssh from instance in region A to instance in region B

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to ssh from an instance in region A to an instance in region B

My firewall is setup correctly source tag I1 dest tag I2 with port 22 AND 3306,

This is my setup (simple drawing):
[image]

How can I ssh into this instance I can ping it because I also have icmp on the firewall

When I do ssh from I1 I got

```
(gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Error while connecting [4033: 'not authorized'].
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: What's your permission? And Did "os-login" feature activate on the instance B?

Comment: I have full permission, don't know about os-login

Comment: This is what [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin) is. Kindly set it up if you haven't already. Steps are in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have the role. Steps can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#grant-permission):

```
roles/iap.httpsResourceAccessor
```

You may also try to enable [OS login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin#enable_os_login) as suggested by guillaume.

> Enable OS Login or OS Login with two-factor authentication by setting the following metadata. If you want enable OS Login for all VMs in a project, set the metadata at the project-level. If you want to enable OS Login for a single VM, set the metadata at the instance-level.
>
> 1. Enable OS Login:
>
> - Key: `enable-oslogin`
> - Value: `TRUE`
>
> 2. (Optional) Enable OS Login 2FA:
>
> - Key: `enable-oslogin-2fa`
> - Value: `TRUE`
>
> When you set OS Login metadata, Compute Engine deletes the VM's `authorized_keys` files and no longer accepts connections from SSH keys that are stored in project or instance metadata.